# IBM Cloud Python SDK: How to retrieve error message on exception?

Tags: python, sdk, ibm-cloud

I am using the [IBM Cloud Platform Services Python SDK](https://github.com/IBM/platform-services-python-sdk) to work with access management tags. For that I am following the [Python example to create a tag](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tagging?code=python#create-tag):

```
create_tag_results = global_tagging_service.create_tag(
  tag_names=['env:example-access-tag'],
  tag_type='access').get_result()

print(json.dumps(create_tag_results, indent=2))
```

I received an error, so I want to catch the exception and print the error message. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that some tests in the SDK GitHub code use the [class ApiException](https://github.com/IBM/python-sdk-core/blob/main/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/api_exception.py) provided by the [IBM Python SDK Core](https://github.com/IBM/python-sdk-core). That class has the attribute **message**. Importing ApiException and then on error printing the message works. The code from above is now:

```
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core import ApiException

...

try:
  create_tag_results = global_tagging.create_tag(
          tag_names=[tagname],
          tag_type=ttype).get_result()
  print(json.dumps(create_tag_results, indent=2))
except ApiException as e:
  print(e.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find additional info re: error-handling [here](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cloud-sdk-common/blob/main/README.md#error-handling).   That link is to a common "README" document that is linked from many of the IBM Cloud SDK README's and contains usage information that is common to all of them.

Comment: I am not sure if this was meant as comment to my answer.

Comment: Yes probably more appropriate as an additional comment under your answer.  I was merely trying to point out that in addition to your answer, there is additional information available in that common README file that is shared by various SDK projecs.